# GCM showing error Request Entity Too Large Error 413

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a table with more than 50000 googleID. I try push notification with GCM and PHP but it showing error `"Request Entity Too Large  Error 413"`. How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

413 is a standard HTTP code. Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)
it says that :

> **413 Request Entity Too Large**
>
> The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process.

It means what it means, you are making a very big request, maybe a long text or json, or whatever, reduce its size...

According to [GCM doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#choose) limitations are like so (I think you use HTTP):

> **Upstream/Downstream messages**
>
> HTTP: Downstream only, cloud-to-device up to 4KB of data.

Comment: It seems you are limited to a 4kB message if you are using HTTP